# Testing containerized microservice with external dependency

Tags: rest, unit-testing, docker, microservices, external-dependencies

So I built a REST API microservice which queries a local Elasticsearch instance and translates the results according to an internal protocol. I built it into a Docker image and I would like to run some unit tests on it in build. Being ES connected to a private Docker network, it isn't reachable by the microservice during build, so the tests obviously fail. I was wondering, is there a way around this situation without having to use some complicated testing framework to do dependency injection? How do you test this kind of containers in your work practice?

Comment: If they test across system boundaries they arent unit tests.

Comment: Yes I figured that out later, I'm gonna fix the title

Answer (score 0):

I would build the application without any testing. Then I would test it using `docker run` so you can take the docker network advantages.

Roughly this is more elegant than test in the middle of the build:

1. `docker build -t my_app:1.0-early` your application in order to obtain an image.
2. `docker run --network my_test_network my_app:1.0-early /run_test_cases.sh`. Return the properly exit code or text.
3. Depending on the success or not of the test, re tag: `docker tag my_app:1.0`

You will need to have already created a docker network (`docker network create my_test_network`), or better use docker-compose.

Comment: But this means I still have to run the tests myself and clutter the Docker environment, instead of having the tests be triggered on build without creating separate containers for the testing

Comment: It depends on what you mean with "myself". It can be a script. Think that at the end of the day, docker build runs a new container for each layer. If you use some CI system (gitlab, jenkins, bamboo, bitbucket pipeline, etc) this enable you to separate the build stage to the testing stage.